# Windows Mobile v 6.5 connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a problem connecting my windows mobile application developed using vb.net in my SQL server 2008 as my back end. Here is my connection string :
Data Source=STEPH-PC\SQL2008;Initial Catalog= MyDB; User ID = myusername; Password = mypassword;

It always give me an error that SQL server does not exist or access denied. Any help on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't include your **actual** username and password when posting questions. It's for your own good.

Comment: edited already thanks.

Comment: Change to Data Source=STEPH-PC \SQL2008;Initial Catalog= MyDB; User ID = myusername; Password = mypassword;    <Add a space before the instance name. I also read that providing the port may be necessary. Possibly add "Integrated Security=SSPI"

Comment: Hi what is the purpose of space in instance name?

Answer (score 0):

**1- Testing connection Server versus Pocket PC:**

First at all test if your SQL Server CE mobile agent connects to SQL Server CE Server agent. To do this you have to install SQL Server CE 3.5 in the server and in your Pocket PC. Search in google How to install SQL Server CE 3.5. In the process you create a Virtual Directory in Server and in that directory you got a file sqlcesa35.dll, so to test the connection in your Pocket PC browser write: http://ipserver/virtual_directory/sqlcesa35.dll (of course ipserver must be your server IP and virtual_directory must be your virtual directory name). Doing this you have to get in your Pocket PC the message:
**Microsoft SQL Server Compact
Server Agent**

At this point I have to mention that always you must have internet connection.

**2- Retrieving files from the server** (this is a sample code, not debugged, I only have taken some parts from other project and put them here).

```
Function get_companies(ByVal sSucursal As String, ByVal cn_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection, _
    ByVal cmd_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand, ByVal dr_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader) As Boolean

    get_companies = False

    Dim _strRemoteConnect As String
    Dim _strLocalConnect As String
    Dim _strInternetURL As String = sInternetURL
    'The last variable sInternetURL is something like: http://ip_server/virtual_directory/sqlcesa35.dll

    _strRemoteConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & sIPSQLServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & sBDSQLServer & ";User Id=" & sUserSQLServer & ";Password=" & sClaveSQLServer
    'sIPSQLServer is the server ip where is running SQL Server
    'sBDSQLServer is your DataBase server.
    _strLocalConnect = "Data Source=" & sPath & "\" & sDataBase_Interface & "; Password=" & sPassword 
    'sPath is your directory in your Pocket PC, begings with \
    'sDataBase_Interface is the database in my Pocket PC, an .sdf file

    Dim rda As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeRemoteDataAccess = New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeRemoteDataAccess
    rda.InternetLogin = sUserInternet 'a valid user in your domain
    rda.InternetPassword = sClaveInternet
    rda.InternetUrl = _strInternetURL
    rda.LocalConnectionString = _strLocalConnect

    Do While True
        Try
            'In server database there is a table: Monedas
            rda.Pull("_Monedas", "Select Moneda, Descripcion, Abreviada From Monedas Where Sucursal = '" & sSucursal & "'", _
                                        _strRemoteConnect, System.Data.SqlServerCe.RdaTrackOption.TrackingOff)
            Exit Do
        Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
            ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Loop      

    'read the data received, just testing, may be this code not to be here because you process the data outside the function.
    Try
        cmd_Interface.CommandText = "Select Moneda, Descripcion, Abreviada From _Monedas"
        dr_Interface = cmd_Interface.ExecuteReader()

        Do While dr_Interface.Read()
            messagebox.show("Moneda = " & dr_interface("Moneda") & " - " & dr_interface("Descripcion") & " - " & dr_interface("Abreviada"), _
            "Currencies Received", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Loop
        get_companies = true
    Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
        ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)       
    Finally
        'If cn_Interface.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        '    cmd_Interface.Dispose()
        '    cn_Interface.Close()
        '    cn_Interface.Dispose()
        'End If
    End Try
End Function
```

**3- Excecuting a sentence in Database Server from your Pocket PC and Transferring data from Pocket to Server:**

```
    Function EnviarClientesNuevos(ByVal sSucursal As String, ByVal sZona As String, ByVal sRuta As String) As Boolean
    Dim sLineas As String
    Dim nRegs As Integer

    Dim cn_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection
    Dim cmd_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand

    EnviarClientesNuevos = False

    Dim _strRemoteConnect As String
    Dim _strLocalConnect As String
    Dim _strInternetURL As String = sInternetURL

    _strRemoteConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & sIPSQLServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & sBDSQLServer & ";User Id=" & sUserSQLServer & ";Password=" & sClaveSQLServer
    _strLocalConnect = "Data Source=" & sPath & "\" & sDataBase_Interface & "; Password=" & sPassword

    Dim rda As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeRemoteDataAccess = New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeRemoteDataAccess
    rda.InternetLogin = sUserInternet
    rda.InternetPassword = sClaveInternet
    rda.InternetUrl = _strInternetURL
    rda.LocalConnectionString = _strLocalConnect

    Do While True
        If DropTableE("_NEW_CLIENTES_XX") Then
            Try
                '_NEW_CLIENTES_XX is a table in your SQL Server (The server, not the Pocket)
                rda.Pull("_NEW_CLIENTES_XX", "Select Id, Sucursal, Zona, CodCli, Nombre, Direccion, Ruc, Clase, Ruta " & _
                "FROM _NEW_CLIENTES_XX WHERE Sucursal = ''", _strRemoteConnect, SqlServerCe.RdaTrackOption.TrackingOn)
                'In where clause I compare to '' because I only need the structure
                Exit Do
            Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
                ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
                Exit Function
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                Exit Function
            End Try
        End If
    Loop

    Try
        '--
        cn_Interface = New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection
        cn_Interface.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sPath & "\" & sDataBase_Interface & ";Password=" & sPassword
        cn_Interface.Open()

        cmd_Interface = cn_Interface.CreateCommand()
        cmd_Interface.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        '--

        'here I have an open connection to another database in my Mobile Device. Here I have to mention that I work with 2 databases in my mobile device:
        'One database for getting the data from server, I only use it when I get data from server and when I send data to server
        'and other database which is my main database, the database that is used all the day storing customers transactions.
        'here I already have open (outside this function) the connection to this second database, but the sentence are the same above,
        'something like this:
        'Try
        '    cn = New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection
        '    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & sPath & "\" & sDataBase_Ppal & ";Password=" & sPassword
        '    cn.Open()

        '    cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
        '    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        'Read the data from my main Pocket PC database          
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CodCli, Nombre, Direccion, Ruc, Clase From CLIENTES WHERE CLASE IN ('N', 'M')"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dr.Read()
            'Insert the data in the table structure that I get above.
            'remember that this table is in the database that only is used when transferring data, its a temporal database.
            cmd_Interface.CommandText = "INSERT INTO _NEW_CLIENTES_XX (Sucursal, Zona, CodCli, Nombre, Direccion, Ruc, Clase, Ruta) " & _
                              "VALUES('" & sSucursal & "', '" & sZona & "', " & dr("CodCli") & ", '" & _
                              dr("Nombre") & "', '" & dr("Direccion") & "', '" & dr("Ruc") & "', '" & _
                              dr("Clase") & "', '" & sRuta & "')"

            nRegs = cmd_Interface.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Loop
        dr.Close() : dr.Dispose()           
    Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
        ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
        Exit Function
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        Exit Function
    Finally
        Try
            dr.Close()
            dr.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        'If cn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        '    cmd.Dispose()
        '    cn.Close()
        '    cn.Dispose()
        'End If

        If cn_Interface.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
            cmd_Interface.Dispose()
            cn_Interface.Close()
            cn_Interface.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try

    Do While True
        Try
            'I excecute a sentence in the Server. I delete the data in _NEW_CLIENTES_XX which is a work table in SQL server.
            rda.SubmitSql("Delete From _NEW_CLIENTES_XX Where Sucursal = '" & sSucursal & "' AND Zona = '" & sZona & "' And Ruta = '" & sRuta & "'", _strRemoteConnect)

            'I send the data to server
            rda.Push("_NEW_CLIENTES_XX", _strRemoteConnect, System.Data.SqlServerCe.RdaBatchOption.BatchingOn)

            EnviarClientesNuevos = True

            Exit Do
        Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
            ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
            Exit Function
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Function
        End Try
    Loop        
End Function
```

Generalities:

```
Function DropTableP(ByVal sTabla As String) As Boolean
    'Dim cn_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection
    'Dim cmd_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand
    'Dim dr_Interface As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader
    Dim nRegs As Integer

    Try
        'cn_Interface = New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" & sPath & "\" & sDataBase_Ppal & "; Password=" & sPassword)
        'cn_Interface.Open()

        'cmd_Interface = cn_Interface.CreateCommand()
        'cmd_Interface.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Select TABLE_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES Where TABLE_NAME = '" & sTabla & "'"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.Read() Then
            dr.Close()
            dr.Dispose()

            cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE " & sTabla
            nRegs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            DropTableP = True
        Else
            dr.Close()
            dr.Dispose()
            DropTableP = True
        End If
    Catch exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
        ShowErrorSqlServerCE(exc)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'If cn_Interface.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        '    cn_Interface.Close()
        '    cn_Interface.Dispose()
        'End If
    End Try
End Function

Sub ShowErrorSqlServerCE(ByVal exc As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException)
    Dim bld As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim err As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeError
    Dim errorCollection As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeErrorCollection = exc.Errors
    Dim errPar As String
    Dim numPar As Integer

    ' Loop through all of the errors.
    For Each err In errorCollection
        bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Error Code: " & err.HResult.ToString("X"))
        bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Message   : " & err.Message)
        bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Minor Err.: " & err.NativeError)
        bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Source    : " & err.Source)

        ' Loop through all of the numeric parameters for this specific error.
        For Each numPar In err.NumericErrorParameters
            If numPar <> 0 Then
                bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Num. Par. : " & numPar.ToString())
            End If
        Next numPar

        ' Loop through all of the error parameters for this specific error.
        For Each errPar In err.ErrorParameters
            If errPar <> [String].Empty Then
                bld.Append(ControlChars.Cr & " Err. Par. : " & errPar)
            End If
        Next errPar

        ' Finally, display this error.
        MessageBox.Show(bld.ToString(), "SQL Server CE")

        ' Empty the string so that it can be used again.
        bld.Remove(0, bld.Length)
    Next err
End Sub
```

As I said above: the code that I put here needs to be debugged...I have only extracted some parts from my project and put here. Hope this will help you!